# Why does this conditional statement, based on exit code, work in the reverse of what is expected?

Tags: shell-script, exit-status

**The script is `test.sh`.**

```
#!/bin/sh

if cmp -s file.a file.b; then
  echo diff
else
  echo same
fi
```

When checking the exit code from `cmp -s` I see:

**When `file.a` and `file.b` are different.**

```
cmp -s file.a file.b
echo $?
1
```

**When `file.a` and `file.b` are the same.**

```
cmp -s file.a file.b
echo $?
0
```

Why then does the conditional statement seem to operate in the reverse?

**When `file.a` and `file.b` are different.**

```
./test.sh
same
```

**When `file.a` and `file.b` are the same.**

```
./test.sh
diff
```

This isn't the first time I've seen this. I must be misunderstanding how the `if` statement interprets the exit code, or maybe it isn't the exit code at all?

Comment: Yes, the shell's "success" status is the opposite of the C boolean values.

Comment: The POSIX shell reference for `if` -- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07

Comment: Ok. Thank you. This just seems backwards from my logic. Traditionally, I think of zero as false, and non-zero as true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why are the definition of true and false in stdbool.h the exact opposite from the UNIX programs true and false?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/641098/100397)

Comment: @Appleoddity, yep, it is backwards wrt. everything else. But it always has been, and always will be. It does have the upside that programs can return multiple _different_ exit codes indicating failures